# Cannot connect to RDS Writer Endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am only able to connect to a MySQL Aurora cluster's **reader endpoint** and **read replica instance endpoints**. However, connection timeouts occur when connecting to the cluster's **writer endpoint** and the **primary writer instance's endpoint**.

Additional details:

- Using MySQL Workbench
- Using Cluster's master username/password
- Access to VPC through VPN
- Cluster SG has VPN IP range whitelisted
- Traffic allowed through subnet NACL's
- Cluster instances in private subnets

Any thoughts what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the writers instance endpoint? Does that also not work?

Comment: @big-K connecting to either the cluster writer endpoint or the instance writer's endpoint are both unsuccessful. Only the cluster and instance readonly endpoints are successful

Comment: are the SG configured on the reader and writer the same , are they in the same Region?

Comment: Can you verify that ALL subnets involved in the cluster have the same NACL rules? Also, can you check that ALL subnets in the cluster use the same Route Table?

Comment: This is a networking issue, there's not enough information here to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had this issue.

I configured my testing AWS Aurora RDS as public. I could connect to the reader instance but not the writer instance from the Internet.

**Resolution**
The resolution for me was to create a 'DB Subnet Group' that only includes the subnets my systems have access to (as permitted by security groups and network ACLs), and use the 'DB Subnet Group' when launching an AWS Aurora RDS.

**Details** The issue for me was when I configured my AWS Aurora RDS, I selected the VPC, set RDS to public, but I let AWS create 'DB Subnet Group'. If you let AWS create the 'DB Subnet Group', AWS will include ALL subnets in the VPC (both public and private) into the 'DB Subnet Group'. Thus when my Aurora RDS writer instance was initiated (even though it was set to public) , it ended up in a private subnet, which makes it inaccessible from Internet. My reader instance was initiated in a public subnet, which I could access.

**Other** If this was not your issue, try checking:

- Your AWS Aurora RDS 'security group' to ensure that it has inbound rules to port 3306 (or whatever port you configured your DB)
- The network acl of the subnets defined in 'DB Subnet Group' to ensure that they allow traffic in/out.

You can check your 'DB Subnet Group' subnets, 'VPC Security Group', etc., by selecting your DB instance (NOT cluster) and look under 'Connectivity & Security'

[image]

Comment: I believe this was my issue, I initially created the DB as public, then I switched over to private because that's what I wanted. It then would only allow me to connect to the reader endpoint (I only had one instance). I couldn't figure anything out so I just created a new DB and it worked perfectly. Appreciate this post though,  helped me figure out what may have gone wrong.